# Does Google Drive Android API help my application to work in background?

Tags: google-drive-android-api

I have read Google Drive API documentation but I'm not able to understand the following:

Can files and folder be created and modified on drive in background of app?
My application needs working of drive in background.

Comment: Have you got solution for uploading files on google drive in background.?

Answer (score 0):

## For Files:

If you will check [**"Working with File Contents"**](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/files):

> *Lifecycle of a Drive file*
>
> The Drive Android API lets your app access files even if the device is offline. To support offline cases, the API implements a sync engine, which *runs in the background to upstream and downstream changes as network access is available and to resolve conflicts*.

Check this image from the document.
[image]

*The lifecycle of a DriveFile object*:

> - Perform an initial download request if the file is not yet synced to the local context but the user wants to open the file. The API handles this automatically when a file is requested.
> - Open the contents of a file. This creates a temporary duplicate of the file's binary stream which is only available to your application.
> - Read or modify the file contents, making changes to the temporary duplicate.
> - Commit or discard any file content changes that have been made.
> - If there are changes, the file contents are queued for upload to sync them back to the server.

Google API does support running in background. For folders there is no documentation regarding creating of folder can be done in background, but I think same implementation can be done.

I hope this helps.